# 2D JSON Array Not Generated in Correctly Java

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to generate 2d JSON Array in Java using Json Object, JSON Array. The 2d array being generated is valid but the ordering of elements is wrong.

**Java Code...**

```
        JSONObject root1 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject c01 = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject c11 = new JSONObject();

        JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray arrayButton= new JSONArray();
        JSONArray arrayelements= new JSONArray();
        JSONObject elementsObj = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject defaultAction = new JSONObject();

        root1.put("recipient", c01);
        root1.put("message", c11);

        c01.put("id", userId);
        c11.put("attachment", attachment);

        attachment.put("type", "template");
        attachment.put("payload", payload);

        payload.put("template_type", "generic");
        payload.put("elements", arrayelements);

        arrayelements.put(elementsObj);

        elementsObj.put("title", "Sample Title");
        elementsObj.put("image_url", "https://google.com/");
        elementsObj.put("subtitle", "Sample Sub Title");
        elementsObj.put("default_action", defaultAction);

            defaultAction.put("type", "web_url");
            defaultAction.put("url", "https://www.google.com/");
            defaultAction.put("messenger_extensions", "true");
            defaultAction.put("webview_height_ratio", "tall");
            defaultAction.put("fallback_url", "https://www.google.com/");

        elementsObj.put("buttons", arrayButton);

        JSONObject buttons1 = new JSONObject();
        buttons1.put("type", "web_url");
        buttons1.put("url", "https://google.com");
        buttons1.put("title", "show website");
        arrayButton.put(buttons1);

        JSONObject buttons2 = new JSONObject();
        buttons2.put("type", "postback");
        buttons2.put("title", "Hi There");
        buttons2.put("payload", "sample payload");
        arrayButton.put(buttons2);
```

**Expected Output**

```
    {
    "recipient":{
    "id":"USER_ID"
      },
     "message":{
"attachment":{
  "type":"template",
  "payload":{
    "template_type":"generic",
    "elements":[
       {
        "title":"Sample title",
        "image_url":"https://google.com/company_image.png",
        "subtitle":"We\'ve got the right hat for everyone.",
        "default_action": {
          "type": "web_url",
          "url": "https://google.com/",
          "messenger_extensions": true,
          "webview_height_ratio": "tall",
          "fallback_url": "https://google.com/"
        },
        "buttons":[
          {
            "type":"web_url",
            "url":"https://google.com",
            "title":"View Website"
          },{
            "type":"postback",
            "title":"Start Chatting",
            "payload":"Sample payload"
          }              
        ]      
      }
    ]
    }
   }
  }
 }
```

**Current Output**

```
       {  
       "recipient":{  
       "id":"988459377921053"
        },
       "message":{  
  "attachment":{  
     "payload":{  
        "elements":[  
           {  
              "buttons":[  
                 {  
                    "type":"web_url",
                    "title":"show website",
                    "url":"https://google.com"
                 },
                 {  
                    "payload":"sample payload",
                    "type":"postback",
                    "title":"Hi There"
                 }
              ],
              "image_url":"https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/fls-items-dev/sample-item-4-95/post/sample-item-4-95-primary-4495.png",
              "subtitle":"Sample Sub Title",
              "title":"Sample Title",
              "default_action":{  
                 "fallback_url":"https://www.frrndlease.com/",
                 "webview_height_ratio":"tall",
                 "messenger_extensions":"true",
                 "type":"web_url",
                 "url":"https://www.frrndlease.com/ItemDetails?uid=wilson-kid-235"
              }
           }
        ],
        "template_type":"generic"
     },
     "type":"template"
     }
    }
  }
```

The order of buttons array, objects template_type & type are inverse. I'm creating nested Json objects and adding them from the outer level to the inner level still the output JSON is not as expected. Can't understand where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Does the order of the JSON entries really matter to you?  In most use cases, you would be accessing things by key anyway, rather than iterating in some sequence.

Comment: Actually I'm sending the json to an external API. That API is returning error "400-Bad request"..Don't know how it is parsing json. Hence wanted to correct the order.

Comment: I'm suspicious now.  The very order you see in your current output depends on the interpretation of a parser.  Are you sure there isn't some other problem?  I'll bet 90% that the API is accessing your input by key, in which case the order won't matter.

Comment: Ok..Is There any problem with the code that generated the JSON. Any JSON obj missed? That's the only thing I can think of..

Comment: How can I answer that?  Maybe you should include a link to the API's documentation.

Comment: I mean the java code which i used to generate the JSON..The expected output is the correct format..

Comment: If the expected output as a string looks correct then it probably is.  Remember, the API doesn't know or care about your Java code, it just seez whatever JSON string you send over.

Comment: This looks correct. Are you sure you sending content_type in your request? Please check the documentation once again. I iterate there is nothing wrong.